# ExoPlayer for Android, lcoal media file play issue

Tags: android, exoplayer

I want to play the local media file on exoplayer.
But when I run it, only the app runs, there are no errors, and there is no response.
What's the problem?
I haven't solved it for 2 weeks.
The bottom is the overall code.

```
private PlayerView playerView;
private SimpleExoPlayer player;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    playerView = findViewById(R.id.player_view);

}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    player = new SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(this).build();
    playerView.setPlayer(player);

    String filePath = "/storage/emulated/0/test.mkv";
    File file = new File(filePath);
    if(new File(filePath).exists()) {
      Log.e("exoPlayer", "File exists");
    }else{
      Log.e("exoPlayer", "File no exits");
    }
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(filePath);

    DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(
            this,
            Util.getUserAgent(this, getString(R.string.app_name)));
    ProgressiveMediaSource mediaSource = new ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
            .createMediaSource(uri);

    player.prepare(mediaSource);
    player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    playerView.setPlayer(null);
    player.release();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In my app I use the similar example:

```
public void example(Context context, String filePath ) {
    SimpleExoPlayer player = new SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(context).build();
    MediaItem mediaItem = MediaItem.fromUri(filePath);
    player.setMediaItem(mediaItem);
    player.prepare();
    player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
}
```